# Why am I getting a null pointer exception with this static injection?

Tags: guice

#### JobDriver

```
public class JobDriver {
    @Inject
    static Provider<Manager> managerProvider;


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JobDriver driver = new JobDriver();
        driver.execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        final Manager manager = managerProvider.get();
        manager.execute();
    }
}
```

#### Provider class

```
public class ManagerProvider implements Provider<Manager> {

    public Manager get() {
       return new Manager();
    }
}
```

### configuration

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        requestStaticInjection(JobDriver.class);
        bind(Manager.class).toProvider(ManagerProvider.class);
    }
}
```

The injector is started up by spring and in the createInjector method it takes in the module above. Is there a better way to do this? I have two entry points into the system. The one through spring which handles all the requests and the other one which is a scheduled job that triggers the JobDriver class at regular intervals. The spring container is launched when the service starts up so I am assuming at creation time all of the injected objects are available. What am I missing here? I'd like the entire system to share these singleton objects.

Answer (score 4):

As listed in the [`requestStaticInjection` documentation](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-), static injection doesn't happen until an Injector is created. It looks like calls to `JobDriver.main` don't directly create an Injector, so `managerProvider` would remain `null`.

It would be sufficient to create an Injector even if you don't hold onto it:

```
public class JobDriver {
    @Inject
    static Provider<Manager> managerProvider;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Guice.createInjector(new Module());
        final JobDriver driver = new JobDriver();
        driver.execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        final Manager manager = managerProvider.get();
        manager.execute();
    }
}
```

...but if you want to ensure the Injector is created only once per VM you may want to extract its creation into a `synchronized` guarded injector creator method, possibly within its own class.

(Required PSA: Avoid static injection whenever you have a choice, as it can make things hard to reason about and test.)

Comment: Wouldn't the guice injector already have these objects injected (spring calls the class which creates the guice injector)?

Comment: You'll have to tell us that. :) It is definitely the case that calling "java your.package.JobDriver" directly would fail with an NPE, and that Spring creating an Injector with that Module (in the same VM) would succeed _as long as all of that is guaranteed to happen before `JobDriver.main` gets called_. It sounded like the scheduled job invoked JobDriver directly through the first entry point you mentioned.